# Best way to store multiple versions of a record in Graph Database say JanusGraph

Tags: java, graph-databases, janusgraph

Suppose there are multiple versions of a record A say v1, v2,v3 and vn, and A is related to B till version v2 and A is related to C from version v3

Suppose A represent the record Id and vi represent the version where i <= n

So the Graph Relationship could look like Av1 -> Bv1 (Reads as A version v1 is related to B version v1)
Similarly Av2 -> Bv2, Av3 -> Cv1 and so on.

So what could be the best way to store these kind of versioned relationship in Graph database like Janusgraph?

Storing separate vertex for each version will cause storage size to be increased, is there any good approach where storage size can be kept minimal and still we are able to query "give me all related records for record A with version 1" ?

I am trying to create vertex for each version of a record in Graph database but this is causing the Graph database size to increased exponentially as there are multiple updates coming for the same record and with new version we need to create new vertices and edges to maintain the relationships

Comment: For inspiration, see: https://www.datastax.com/blog/gremlins-time-machine

Comment: Is the concern more over running out of storage or the cost of storage? A key thing to consider is query efficiency. You only have 3 basic building blocks to work with.  Nodes, Edges, and Properties. Using nodes and edges to represent the version chain might use more storage, but might also allow simple query writing and efficient query execution.

Comment: What information will you need to retrieve that is unique to each version?

Comment: Thanks Kelvin, the concern is related to the overall storage costs as their are millions of records already without using the version and facing latency issues in multiple hop queries, as one record could be updated multiple times may be more than 1000 and one record is related to more than 10000 related records in the  Graph, so just thinking to avoid storage cost, I require to retrieve the relationship based on version, so if record 1 version 1 is related to record to version 1 and record 1 version 2 is related to record 2 version 2, so I require to return versioned graph  for record r1:v1